# opa : deploy with node.js

Tags: web, opa

What would you advise to deploy an opa app under linux using the node.js backend ?

When using the "native" backend, I used to deploy the *.exe in /usr/local/bin/.

Now, with the node.js backend, the .js files seems to need the extra directory _depends.

Should I put my whole opa project in the home of the web user, and run the application from here  ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

**update**:

You can try the new bundle option (available in the last nightlies):

```
$ opa --bundle myapp.tar.gz myapp.opa 
$ tar -xvf myapp.tar.gz 
$ du -h -d 1
   7,8M ./node_modules
```

Use a `package.json` to config the extra node modules dependencies, some cloud provider will use it. Or add them in the node_modules directory with `npm install mongodb formidable nodemailer simplesmtp imap`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your nodejs file is named `toto.js`, and you have `toto_depends`, you can use `opa bundle toto` in your project directory.

This will bundle all required files and dependencies in a `toto.opa-bundle` folder, and then tar-gz it in `toto.opa-bundle.tar.gz`.

This is an alpha tool for the moment. It has a very naive way of copying files in the opa-bundle folder.